# Changing the value of a field when clicking next to a field or on a label (Microsoft Dynamics CRM)

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

Noticed the strange behavior of the system. When the user clicks not on the field, but next to it or on the label of this field, the field reacts in the same way as when clicking on it. This behavior is typical for all entities of the system. There was a problem with fields of type "Two options". Since the value in the field can change to the opposite if the user accidentally clicks next to it.  Question: is this the standard behavior of the CRM system, which cannot be changed, or is there some way to make the fields changeable only when you click on them?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Is the version you are using On-Premise?

Because I just checked with a trial Online and the behavior you described does not appear with `Two Options` field. With a `text` field if you click on the label the textbox containing the value get selected, but when you click on the label of a `Two Options` field the value does not change.

If this is On-Premise I suggest to check if there are patches to apply to your version.

Comment: Yes, it's On-Premise. Thank you that you check it. Usually, the installations are updated automatically after they are released.